# .NET Core service stalling under load due to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I had a ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.8) web service running on a Windows Server, that made lots of outgoing HTTP requests using `HttpWebRequest` (synchronous). It was handling thousands of concurrent requests without any trouble.

Recently, I migrated the service/middleware to ASP.NET Core (runtime 3.1) running on Ubuntu Server, using the updated `HttpWebRequest` (synchronous).

Now this service is stalling under a load test with just a few hundred concurrent requests. System journal/logs indicate that health check (heartbeat) cannot reach the service after a few minutes. It starts out fine, but after a few minutes it slows down and eventually halts (no response but it doesn't crash dotnet though), and then starts working again after 5-10 minutes without any intervention, and repeats this same behavior every few minutes.

I'm not sure if this is due to port exhaustion or a deadlock. If I load test the service by skipping all `HttpWebRequest` calls, then it works fine, so I'm suspecting it has to do something with `HttpWebRequest` causing an issue under stress of traffic.

Looking at the .NET Core codebase, it seems like `HttpWebRequest` (synchronous) creates a new `HttpClient` for each request (client is not cached due to parameters in my case), and executes [HttpClient synchronously](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Requests/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,1173) like:

```cs
public override WebResponse GetResponse()
{
    :
    :
    return SendRequest(async: false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    :
    :
}

private async Task<WebResponse> SendRequest(bool async)
{
    :
    :
    _sendRequestTask = async ?
        client.SendAsync(...) :
        Task.FromResult(client.Send(...));

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await _sendRequestTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    :
    :
}
```

Official [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) from Microsoft is to use `IHttpClientFactory` or `SocketsHttpHandler` for better performance. I can make our service use a singleton `SocketsHttpHandler` and new `HttpClient`'s per outgoing request (with the shared handler) to reuse & close sockets better, but my main concern is (below):

The service is based on synchronous code, so I'll have to use asynchronous `HttpClient` synchronously, probably using the same `method.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` technique as official .NET Core code above. While a singleton `SocketsHttpHandler` may help avoid port exhaustion, could concurrent synchronous execution still result in the stalling problem due to deadlocks like the native `HttpWebRequest`?

Also, is there an approach (another synchronous HTTP client for .NET Core, setting 'Connection: close' header etc.) to smoothly making lots of concurrent HTTP requests synchronously without port exhaustion or deadlocks, just like it worked smoothly earlier with `HttpWebRequest` in .NET Framework 4.8?

Just to clarify, all `WebRequest` related objects are closed/disposed properly in the code, `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` is set to `int.MaxValue`, `nginx` (proxy to dotnet) has been [tuned](https://github.com/denji/nginx-tuning), `sysctl` has been tuned as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this is due to port exhaustion or a deadlock.

Sounds more like [thread pool exhaustion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall) to me.

> The service is based on synchronous code, so I'll have to use asynchronous HttpClient synchronously

Why?

The best solution to thread pool exhaustion is to rewrite blocking code to be asynchronous. There were places in ASP.NET pre-Core that required synchronous code (e.g., MVC action filters and child actions), but ASP.NET Core is fully asynchronous, including the middleware pipeline.

If you absolutely *cannot* make the code properly asynchronous for some reason, the only other workaround is to increase the minimum number of threads in the thread pool on startup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stephen. I agree with your suggestion that async is the best solution, and it's on my to-do list but it'll take a few weeks to refactor and test, so I'm trying to figure out the cause and a temporary workaround to this issue. So far, I've found that `ThreadPool` has around 32743 available worker threads (of total 32767) and all 1000 available async threads just before the issue kicks in, when established inbound connections burst beyond 1000 or so (as per `netstat`) while outbound stay under 50, so it may not be related to `HttpWebRequest`. Still scratching my head.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I think it is indeed a thread pool exhaustion issue. I took a process dump (using `dotnet-trace`) under heavy load, analyzed it (using `PrefView`), and noticed a bunch of events under `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/ThreadPoolWorkerThreadAdjustment/Adjustment` with the new worker thread count going up-to 90 and adjustment reason being `Starvation`. I'm going to change the sync/blocking operations to async. I'm still puzzled as to why it worked (no thread exhaustion) with .NET Framework 4, and what changed in .NET Core to surface this issue? Would you have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the details, but there were several changes between .NET Framework and .NET Core in terms of when things are punted to the thread pool. There's also the possibility that it's an OS difference; Windows drivers are forced to be asynchronous, but Linux allows synchronous drivers.

Comment: Ok, with async code and high-load (few hundred requests per second, and short bursts), should I still set `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` to be safe or just rely on `ThreadPool`'s thread management algorithm?

Comment: @Nick: I don't have a lot of experience running high-load servers on Linux. I'd say to start with the default in a prod-like setting and then stress-test and adjust if necessary.