# How is it possible to check if limitation of outbound requests from IIS or windows server has been exceeded?

Tags: performance, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a web application hosted on iis on windows server. My API uses external APIs as a source for data. There is metrics in my API that show that when there are too many requests to my API, getting response from external APIs takes longer than usual and that elapsed time is usually 3 seconds+time that was really spent by external API to proccess request.

External APIs in fact are soap-services on ESB, if it matters.

Metrics of external APIs and metrics of net channels between my server and ESB and between ESB and external servers don't show these 3 seconds anywhere. It happens not with all external APIs, but with most of them. It seems like it never happens to database requests from my API.

So it seems like there might be a limitation of outbound requests from iis or from app pool or from windows server itself. But I don't know how to check it, where to look. May be perfomance monitor, but there are tons of metrics - what should I choose?

Comment: What web framework do you use? ASP.NET 4.x/ASP.NET Core or any other?

Comment: @LexLi .net Core 5

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your case, you can take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/70xadeyt(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: There can be many reasons, but without profiling carefully it would be impossible to tell at this moment. Performance counters are not as straightforward as a good performance profiler, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193405/net-core-service-stalling-under-load-due-to-httpwebrequest